# Logged in user can not save data to database

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-1.7

I am using django 1.7 and trying to create new product in database. I am able to create product when i logged out (by providing spesific user id as "form.User_IDUser_id= 3" cause user cannot be null), but it is not working for logged in user shows below in address bar and nothing happen.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/add_product/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=kfGpEA6ZC32Lad9m9uwWZEhElwBGLHPA&csrfmiddlewaretoken=kfGpEA6ZC32Lad9m9uwWZEhElwBGLHPA&Category_IDCategory=66&DealType=Rent&Title=kkjkj&Price=78&Description=kjjk&save=Save
```

will be glad if you help.

models.py

```
 DealType_Choice = (
    ("Sale", "Sale"),
    ("Rent", "Rent"),
    ("Swap", "Swap"),
    ("Free", "Free"),
    ("Announ", "Announ"),

)
 DealType = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, choices=DealType_Choice)
 Title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
 Description = models.TextField(blank=False)
 Price = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, null=True)
 User_IDUser = models.ForeignKey(User)
 Category_IDCategory = models.ForeignKey(Category)
 PubDate = models.DateField("Publication Data")

 def __str__(self):
     return self.Title
```

views.py

```
def add_product(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      product_form= ProductForm(request.POST)
      if product_form.is_valid():
          form=product_form.save(commit=False)
          form.User_IDUser= request.user
          form.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
   else:
       product_form= ProductForm()
   return render(request, 'add_productts.html', {'product_form':product_form})
```

template

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

    <h1>Add Product</h1>{% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy product_form %}


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: how do you successfully save in case of not logged user?

Comment: i gave spesific user id as form.User_IDUser_id= 3 to check it is actually working.

Comment: What is the HTML rendered by `{% crispy product_form %}`? It seems the form gets send with the `GET` method, not `POST`, based on your url.

Comment: @knbk youre right, I checked the terminal and it shows [03/Jan/2015 12:17:30] "GET /add_product/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=gYlgpYbbw3uyxQWdRpDCLUb0woctIaH2&csrfmiddle.. how can i fix it? btw do you mean the name of html? it s add_productts.html.

Comment: No, I mean the html code that's on the actual page, the `<form>` tags etc. Open the page in your browser and use 'Right Click > View page source', or the equivalent in your browser.

Comment: @knbk Many many thanks for directing me to the solution. It turned out there is an unclosed tag in index.html.  Such a stupid mistake.